# Qt openGL ES library linking error

Tags: qt, opengl-es, linker, linker-errors

While building a game code in Qt simulator I'm getting the following error:

> -1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libEGL.lib'

I have added following code to add library files:

> INCLUDEPATH +=
>   C:\Imagination_Technologies\POWERVR_SDK\OGLES2_WINDOWS_X86EMULATION_2.08.28.0634\Builds\OGLES2\Include\
>   LIBS +=
>   -LC:\Imagination_Technologies\POWERVR_SDK\OGLES2_WINDOWS_X86EMULATION_2.08.28.0634\Builds\OGLES2\WindowsX86\Lib\
>   -llibEGL -llibGLESv2
>
> LIBS += -llibEGL -llibGLESv2

Comment: Please provide a list of files under C:\Imagination_Technologies\POWERVR_SDK\OGLES2_WINDOWS_X86EMULATION_2.08.28.0634\Builds\OGLES2\WindowsX86\Lib\

Comment: following 4 files are there in this folder:                                                           1)libEGL.dll                                                        2)libEGL obj file                                                       3)libGLESv2.dll                                                     4)libGLESv2 obj file

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since I stopped programming under Windows, but as far as I can remember qmake uses the same mechanism used in Linux on all the supported OS (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html). Which means you should write:

```
LIBS += -LC:\Imagination_Technologies\POWERVR_SDK\OGLES2_WINDOWS_X86EMULATION_2.08.28.0634\Builds\OGLES2\WindowsX86\Lib\ -lEGL -lGLESv2
```

provided the path is correct of course (note that I removed the 'lib').

Comment: It should work according to the documentation: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs. Try specifying the suffix. If that is not working either, try to simply specify simply the entire path of the file, including the file name. I don't see any spaces in the path so $$quote shouldn't be necessary.